# Python, Paramiko: How to do a "ssh -n user@host cmd" using paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to execute a command remotely via SSH from Python, and in this particular case need *stdin* to be redirected to /dev/null.

That is, the same as using the OpenSSH client with its -n flag:

```
ssh -n user@host cmd
```

How do you achieve this (-n) with [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/)?

paramiko.SSHClient.exec_command() doesn't seem to allow this, but maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I understand your question incorrectly: you don't need to achieve this. Nothing is automatically read from stdin/written to the remote process' stdin unless you yourself explicitly do so. So you don't need to prevent reading from stdin from happening?

EDIT: there might be an issue if the remote process expects data on stdin, and keeps waiting for it? Try calling `shutdown_write()` on the channel:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
stdin.channel.shutdown_write()
```

Comment: Well, in this case it seems I do. I'm trying to execute some powershell commands on the remote host, and have spend hours trying to make it work with Paramiko. I have finally concluded that for this to work I need to do "ssh -n user@host cmd", whereas "ssh user@host cmd" will simply hang forever. Doing it by hand from the commandline using the OpenSSH client confirms that without the -n flag, the remote command hangs.

Comment: Wish I had asked hours ago. Thank you, Steven! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would ditch paramiko and start using [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.2/index.html). It will let you do remote calls on the system. It uses paramiko for the ssh connection and provides the nice clean interface for doing alot more.

I am not sure why you need to pip stdin to /dev/null but there are settings to suppress it with fabric.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this when time permits. Right now I have a deadline that says I use Stevens solution. :)