# paramiko exec_command disable stdin

Tags: python, paramiko

Using `paramiko.SSHClient.exec_command()`, can I mimic ssh `-n` command line option?

```
-n' Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).
```

My only solution has been to clutter the command and explicitly manage stdin.

---

In this example, the bash script waits for one line of stdin.  Inspecting exit_status allows me to determine if the remote script has completed.

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> client = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> client.connect(**kwargs)

>>> i, o, e = client.exec_command("cat /tmp/one_input.sh")
>>> o.channel.exit_status_ready()
True
>>> print o.read()
echo "started"
read
echo "done"

>>> i, o, e = client.exec_command("bash /tmp/one_input.sh")
>>> o.channel.exit_status_ready()
False
>>> i.write("\n")
>>> o.channel.exit_status_ready()
True

>>> i, o, e = client.exec_command("bash /tmp/one_input.sh </dev/null")
>>> o.channel.exit_status_ready()
True
```

Comment: Turns out similar question already exists, I just couldn't find it til seeing Related posts here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555805/python-paramiko-how-to-do-a-ssh-n-userhost-cmd-using-paramiko

Answer (score 0):

`stdin.channel.shutdown_write()` works

References:

1. http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.shutdown_write
2. [Python, Paramiko: How to do a "ssh -n user@host cmd" using paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555805/python-paramiko-how-to-do-a-ssh-n-userhost-cmd-using-paramiko)

Comment: So please do not duplicate answers. Instead close your question as a duplicate.